# Trying to make a 3D cube with controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a 3D cube with controls in -> three.js
and I don't know what's wrong.
I'm not sure if I'm supposed to download anything more than three.js

when I tried to create a static cube it worked and also when I tried to make it move continuously
but why can't I control it with the cursor?

```
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Our Javascript will go here.
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.color(0xffffff);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            camera = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;

            controls.screenSpacePanning = false;

            controls.minDistance = 100;
            controls.maxDistance = 500;

            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
            scene.add(cube);

            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            light.position.set( - 1, - 1, - 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


        }

        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update(); // only required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        animate();



    </script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that you include the OrbitControls. They are in `examples\js\controls`